# what could be the correct regex for reading first few bytes in fixed size fron file and reading remaining bytes from first regex's (.*) part in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, file, byte

I am reading one file using ruby in which I have written regexp in my code as below assuming it will read first 4 bytes from file, next four bytes, next four bytes, rest of the bytes in file except last 8 bytes from file.
Now I am trying to further split bytes from these variable size data (.*) using following code.Is this correct way? I am getting results but still unsure if they are correct or not.

Is this the correct way to scan contents of remaining asterisk part of first regex in first `do..end` and then again scan remaining  bytes in second `do..end` regex ?

```
File.open(filename,'rb') do |file|
file.read.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)(.{8})/m).each do |a,b,c,d,e|
   puts "\Content 1:#{a}\n\n"
   b1 = b.unpack("N")
   puts "\n\nContent 2:\n#{b1}\n\n"
   puts "\n\nContent 3:\n#{c.unpack("N")}\n\n"
          d.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)/).each do |p,q,r,s|
              puts "\n\nPContent 4:\n#{p.unpack("N")}\t"
              puts "Content 5\n:#{q.unpack("e")}\t"
              puts "Content 6:\n#{r.unpack("e")}\t"
              s.scan(/(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.*)/).each do |f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p|
                  puts "Content 7:#{f.unpack("e")}"
                  puts "Content 8:#{g.unpack("B")}"
                  puts "Content 9:#{h.unpack("B")}"
                  puts "Content 10:#{i.unpack("B")}"
                  puts "Content 11:#{j.unpack("e")}"
                  puts "Content 12:#{k.unpack("e")}"
                  puts "Content 13:#{l.unpack("e")}"
                  puts "Content 14:#{m.unpack("B")}"
                  puts "Content 15:#{n.unpack("B")}"
                  puts "Content 16:\t#{o}#{p}"
              end
          end
```

Comment: I've posted this at http://rubular.com/r/L4xnGbvukW for you, it's an awesome 'instant' tool for playing around with regexp's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me.

A suggestion is to anchor your scan at the start and end of the string by using \A and \z

```
/\A...\z/
```

In my opinion this makes it easier to quickly see that you want to match the entire string, rather than using #scan to iterate on matches. It may perform faster too.

Comment: how can I detect null terminted ASCII (0x00) string?